# Store workbooks in a collection or an array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, object, collections

I recently posted a question about how to "group" several open workbooks (not all workbooks). A couple techniques were mentioned, all of which I think I could make work but one technique seemed to stick out at me as being exactly what I needed. Creating a collection and putting the workbooks in the collection. Then I can refer to this collection throughout my program as needed. So... I began reading up on / learning about collections. However, Several articles compared collections to being similar to arrays. Which had me second guessing myself as to which one I should use. I am having trouble understanding if an array can even store "objects"? For example can an array store several "objects"? i.e: store several "workbooks"?

Comment: Ugh... Ok... So... If I know I am putting 5 workbooks into this array/collection and it will always be these 5 workbooks and that wont change. Should I use an array? or a collection? I will be doing thing like for each workbook in collection/array copy range D1:G1 and paste somewhere... stuff like that

Comment: Use whatever is easiest for you.

Comment: Thank you... I think collection may be easier for me in this situation... but I will try some things tomorrow and see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to store workbooks in an array we can create an array of workbooks:

```
Sub kjkj()

    Dim wkbks(1 To 4) As Workbook

    Set wkbks(1) = workbooks.Open(....)
    Set wkbks(2) = workbooks.Open(....)
    Set wkbks(3) = workbooks.Open(....)
    Set wkbks(4) = workbooks.Open(....)

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To 4
        With wkbks(i)
            'do something
        End With
    Next i


End Sub
```

Comment: Ugh... Ok... So... If I know I am putting 5 workbooks into this array/collection and it will always be these 5 workbooks and that wont change. Should I use an array? or a collection? I will be doing thing like for each workbook in collection/array copy range D1:G1 and paste somewhere... stuff like that

Comment: it is a preference thing.

Comment: Thank you... I think collection may be easier for me in this situation... but I will try some things tomorrow and see